# Retrieving firebase database data from Google Cloud yalm python app

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin, google-cloud-python

I'm building a google cloud function which is launching every 1mins. The purpose is to get data from my database (firebase) and to delete this data if the date of the post is superior to one hour ago.

I was thinking about making a firebase cloud function, and use the settimeout function after one hour. Unfortunately its not possible aparently. So i decided to use the cron functions of gcloud.

Here is my main.py.

```
import webapp2
from gcloud import datastore
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

# Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
cred = credentials.Certificate('key.json')

try:
    # Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
        'databaseURL': 'https://#########.firebaseio.com/'
    })
except:
    print('no need for init firebase')
# As an admin, the app has access to read and write all data, regradless of Security Rules
ref = db.reference('/')



class HourCronPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        ref.child("test").delete()


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/timer', HourCronPage),
    ], debug=True)
```

Here is the error i get from the gcloud console and i've no idea how to solve this:

```
('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(14 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(14 bytes read)) (/base/data/home/apps/s~instavice-application/20180408t195049.408875809865949267/lib/webapp2.py:1552)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~instavice-application/20180408t195049.408875809865949267/lib/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~instavice-application/20180408t195049.408875809865949267/lib/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~instavice-application/20180408t195049.408875809865949267/lib/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~instavice-application/20180408t195049.408875809865949267/lib/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~instavice-application/20180408t195049.408875809865949267/lib/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~instavice-application/20180408t195049.408875809865949267/lib/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~instavice-application/20180408t195049.408875809865949267/main.py", line 25, in get
    ref.child("test").delete()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~instavice-application/20180408t195049.408875809865949267/lib/firebase_admin/db.py", line 282, in delete
    self._client.request('delete', self._add_suffix())
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~instavice-application/20180408t195049.408875809865949267/lib/firebase_admin/db.py", line 774, in request
    return super(_Client, self).request(method, url, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~instavice-application/20180408t195049.408875809865949267/lib/firebase_admin/_http_client.py", line 84, in request
    resp = self._session.request(method, self._base_url + url, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~instavice-application/20180408t195049.408875809865949267/lib/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 198, in request
    self._auth_request, method, url, request_headers)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~instavice-application/20180408t195049.408875809865949267/lib/google/auth/credentials.py", line 121, in before_request
    self.refresh(request)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~instavice-application/20180408t195049.408875809865949267/lib/google/oauth2/service_account.py", line 322, in refresh
    request, self._token_uri, assertion)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~instavice-application/20180408t195049.408875809865949267/lib/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 145, in jwt_grant
    response_data = _token_endpoint_request(request, token_uri, body)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~instavice-application/20180408t195049.408875809865949267/lib/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 106, in _token_endpoint_request
    method='POST', url=token_uri, headers=headers, body=body)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~instavice-application/20180408t195049.408875809865949267/lib/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 124, in __call__
    six.raise_from(new_exc, caught_exc)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~instavice-application/20180408t195049.408875809865949267/lib/six.py", line 737, in raise_from
    raise value
TransportError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(14 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(14 bytes read))
```

Anyone has an idea?

Thank you guys so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set up the same additional dependencies (at least ssl)  required in the App Engine environment: https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#the-app-engine-standard-environment